# SUMIFS formula to fill data in cell depends upon date and name and also keep previous data in a cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an excel with two sheets named `raw` and `data` here

raw sheet :

[image: raw sheet]

date sheet :

[image: data sheet]

In raw sheet I will be uploading data manually.

What I am looking for :

In this, I want to create a formula which will check each name from the `data` sheet in `raw` sheet and it has to pick the `total` value (D column in raw) and update the same in `data` sheet in a cell which matches with last modified date.

For example :

Name is R420864561 and its `last modified` date is 20141201 and `total` value is 10.

[image]

So in my data sheet, it has to be updated like this

[image]

Above, value 10 is updated in a cell which matches the `last modified` from raw sheet with `date` in data sheet, here both are `20141201`.

I am using below formula for this (formula in C3)

```
=SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A3,raw!$C:$C,C$2)
```

Now, if last modified `date` 20141202 with `total` 50

[image]

Now, data sheet will updated like below using above formula

[image]

What I need now :

In above, if I update value in another date, the data updated in previous date is getting changing to 0. But I need to keep that data in that cell, if there is no update in that.

In above case, I need to keep previous data (for date 2014201)10 in data sheet cell `C3`, and update 50 in `D3` (for date 20141202)

[image]

I have added below code with macro, to copy paste the formula value, as simple value

```
 Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In ActiveWindow.RangeSelection
        rngCell.Value = rngCell.Value
    Next rngCell
```

But that is not working here, It still resetting previous value to `0` when I update for a different date.

Any suggestion to correct this is much appreciated

**I have uploaded the copy of the excel which I am working in below location :**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jpubzqbco5mflu5/1.1_test.xlsm?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

you VBA is wrong:
update it using this one:

```
Sub saveMyData()

Set ws = ActiveSheet

ws.Range("C3:E999").Copy

ws.Range("C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("C3").Formula = "=SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A3,raw!$C:$C,C$2)"
Range("D3").Formula = "=SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A3,raw!$C:$C,D$2)"
Range("E3").Formula = "=SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A3,raw!$C:$C,E$2)"

End Sub
```

Here is [***UPDATED***the example sheet to try and see if it works.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2984peh0vsxbxuq/savemydata3.xlsm?dl=0)

it was because your VBA code was mixed up with unncessary codes.

Comment: No Luck.. Unable to keep previous data with this also

Comment: @acr: added a link to example sheet, where it works.

Comment: Tried the new excel. still it is not working for me. I am changing the date in raw 20141201 with value 10,but not seeing any change in data sheet.

Comment: @acr: Yes! because we have run the macro, and cleared the formulas and pasted the values ONLY. So you need to put your formulas back each time you run the macro. The macro works for me and the formulas too.

Comment: If I paste both script in same macro, it has to work right ?, I mean everytime without pasting formula again and again

Comment: @acr: here is the updated file: copying pasting the values as is, and then pasting the formulas back into the cell! BUT, this would again repeat the same problem, because for example, if the formula in C3 is updated, then the value will be erased because the reference in raw is not there anymore! So you can comment out the formula/range you don't want to paste back! , there fore you need to have three macros, the first one pasting back the formula into the C3 and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

This should work assuming your loop is correct.

```
rngCell.Copy
rngCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Try `For Each rngCell In Application.Selection` to start the loop

Answer (score 0):

From all appearances, the problem is with how you are presenting the question and plan to use the raw spreadsheet. From the information provided, it seems like you plan on entering records in raw, but then you also intend to change them. Also, based on your example and how you are describing the problem, it's not clear why you are using SUMIFS rather than INDEX(MATCH).

It would seem that your raw spreadsheet should have multiple records, one for each Name/Last Modified combination, and more than one for each combination to necessitate the use of SUMIFS. Then your formula in data will pick up the relevant info in raw.

If you plan on only having one entry for each Name in raw, and changing the last modified date and the total in raw it seems rather pointless to have separate spreadsheets at all, just enter it into data in the first place under the respective last modified date.